# Change BooleanField whenever object is updated

Tags: django

I have a model with an property called `changed` which I'd like to change to True when the model is changed. But ofcourse I don't want to set it to True on the creation of an object.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  changed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: you can either override the `save()` method or use the signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the save method

```python
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  changed = models.BooleanField(default=False) # no need to use null=True, it would add a third possibility to the boolean (null, True, False) but you could use: 
  # changed = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
  
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self._state.adding is False:
      self.changed = True
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: fixed typo from self._state to self._state.adding

Answer (score 0):

" **on the creation of an object.**" I don't understand this properly. But I assume by default you want to set it null. If so then:

```
changed = models.BooleanField(default=Null, blank=True, null=True)
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Sure, but what about when a change is made to the object? How can I set `changed` to True?

Comment: SomeModel.changed=1 for True or SomeModel.changed=0 for False. This will save as boolen in database.